# Am trying following code but it is showing Exception:java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, exception, cassandra

> 685 [main] INFO org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection - Connected to localhost:9160 using Keyspace demo and CQL version 2.0.0
>   Connected
>   ABC
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: schema
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.(CassandraResultSet.java:121)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:167)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.executeQuery(CassandraStatement.java:227)
>       at App.main(App.java:32)

this is the code :

```
try 
{ 
    Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver"); 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/demo"); 

    if (conn != null)
    {
            System.out.println("Connected");
    }



    //String sql = "INSERT INTO employee (eid,eadd,ename,esal,sex) VALUES (2499,'bangalore','amit',10000,'male')"; 
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 

    //stmt.execute(sql);
    System.out.println("ABC");
    String sql="select *  from employee";       
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    //System.out.println(rs);
    //System.out.println("value inserted");
    while(rs.next()) 
         {

            System.out.println("id="+rs.getString(1));

            System.out.println();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**NoSuchMethod** arises when you have jar conflict. I.e When you build your project with a jar and run your application with a different version jar.

Check whether the versions are same.

The common mistake people do is, Add Jars to Project to build path in eclipse, and again add jars in Server Lib. This is some time vulnerable to jar conflict.

For you Problem. You can do two things

1. Remove the Cassandra Jar from both project build path and server path. And place a clean same jar in both the places.
2. Remove all the jars from build path and server path. Place all the JARS in WEB-INF/lib folder. Now your application is very well portable.

Comment: actually am using linux and i have added all the jar files in run time library folder thats not the problem coz data insertion code is running properly  but fetching the data is not working

Comment: I could not diagonalize fully as I cannot see.But I can make you understand. You exception says org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.(CassandraResultSet.java:121

So, the error is in jar file. You did not face any compilation error because, the jar u added had this method. But while running, the server could not find the method . This is surely bcoz of wrong version. You did not facing problem in insert bcoz, the method is present in both compile and run version. I would suggest to check the version

Comment: i have already included the latest version of org.apache.cassandra package am not getting what you are asking me to do

Comment: my project is simple directory structure nothing like eclipse project and all the jar file i have added in /user/lib/jvm folder and given path in .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

yup @madhairsilence is correct, you got a jar that is not compatible with the jars it was compiled with.  Start anew or check versions of jar files as you have two jars that are incompatible(THEY were not compiled with each other but were compiled with a different version of the jar).